# Laravel get parameters from url

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following in my routes

```
Route::get('c/maintenances/{contractor_user_id}', 'Maintenance\Api\ApiContractorMaintenanceController@index');
```

is there a way for me to get the `/{contractor_user_id}` by reading the url?

For example

```
 $current_url = Request::url();
 dd($current_url);
```

returns

```
"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/c/maintenances/3"
```

Is there a way to alienate the `3` from the url and return it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this `request()->route('contractor_user_id');`

`$request->route('parameter_name')`., where parameter_name refers to what we called the parameter in the route.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/get-laravel-route-parameters-in-middleware

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `request()` helper

```
request()->route('parameter_name')
```

`